# How to create secondary y-axes from a plotly express facetted figure?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I would like to modify a facetted plotly.express figure so that each trace has its own secondary y-axis. I don't want to re-create the figure from scratch using the standard Plotly-python api if possible. See exmaple below.

```py
import plotly.express as px
input_df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(input_df,
    x = 'total_bill',
    y = 'tip',
    color = 'day',
    facet_row = 'smoker',
    facet_col = 'sex',
                    )
fig.layout.width = 800
fig.show()
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

I would like to convert the above so each trace (or color) has its own secondary y-axis. So in this case, I would like 3 additional y-axes for each facet. This is my attempt but it doesn't work. There must be a better way.  I would appreciate any ideas.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

yaxes = []
for trace in fig.data:
    yaxisLabel = trace['yaxis']
    if trace['yaxis'] in  yaxes:
        if yaxisLabel == 'y':
            axisnumber = 0
        else:
            axisnumber = int(trace['yaxis'][1:])
        newAxis_num = axisnumber + 100 * yaxes.count(yaxisLabel)
        exec(f"fig.layout.update(yaxis{newAxis_num} = go.layout.YAxis(overlaying='y', side='right'))")
        trace.update({'yaxis': f'y{newAxis_num}'})

    yaxes.append(yaxisLabel)
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit about your desired result? Would you just like to show *one* trace per facet? Or would you like to *add* a secondary axis to each facet? If the latter is correct, then I find it a bit strange that you'd like to `[...] convert the above so each trace (or color) has its own secondary y-axis` since there are four and not only two traces per facet.

Comment: Vestland, yeah, it's a strange request for this particular example. I would like 3 additional y-axes for each facet. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: @vestland I have editted the question. Thanks for helping me clarify